# Entity Framework property hiding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I'm working with Entity Framework 6.0.2 Code First with Sql Server.

I have a base class called Entity and since we can't extend enums I need to redefine a property type for another class called Company, so I'm using the new keyword to hide the base property and redefine it.

```
public interface IEntity 
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    State State { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public State State { get; set; }
}

public enum State 
{
   Inactive = 0,
   Active = 1
}

public class Company : Entity 
{
   public new CompanyState State { get; set; }
   public string SomeOtherProp { get; set; }
}

public enum CompanyState 
{
   Inactive = 0,
   Active = 1,
   Extra = 2
}
```

The problem I get is when Entity Framework is trying to create the DbContext it crashes with this error: "The item with identity 'State' already exists in the metadata collection. Parameter name: item"

I have a workaround: I could change the State propery in Entity class to int and cast the appropriate enum to int, but I think I'll lose type safety / restriction that the enums have.

I'd like to change the metadata info to avoid this error but I don't know how.

Comment: Why not just add `Extra` to the base enum?  Hiding a property seems like a bad idea in itself, let alone changing the type as well.

Comment: Because the goal was to have only those 2 options and having a way to extend the options with business meanings.

Comment: @DStanley I removed the state from IEntity, but do you think it's a bad idea to redefine a property? Isn't that the point of the new keyword ?

Comment: No, the `new` keyword is to tell the compiler that you are _intentionally_ doing something that is _usually_ a bug.  Hiding properties can cause all sorts of issues - in reality the type has _two_ properties now, so in can cause problem with reflection, confusion as to which property is being accessed, etc.  If it truly is a different property then _give it a different name_.

Comment: IMO that's highly subjective. I aggree that if misused it could cause such problems, but it is trully the same property and not using reflection. It was just an attempt to restrict the allowed values.

Comment: They are _not_ the same property - there are actually _two_ different `State` properties on type `Company` - which one you are accessing depends on the type of the variable that references the instance.  If you look for a `State` property via reflection you will see two different properties.

Comment: Just tested this and you're totally right. I've changed my point of view. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206559/entity-framework-6-1-and-member-hiding-using-new-keyword) found a solution for some similar problem.

Neither your, nor his solution is nice. It is and remains a hack.
I would go with the solution you already mentioned. Change the `state` to `stateId`. And add a State Property to your `Entity`:

```
public State State {get {return (State)stateId;}
```

In your Company override this Property with new:

```
public new CompanyState State {get {return (CompanyState )stateId;}
```

**But I think best solution** would be, to change your inheritance hierarchy. I think either your IEntity should not have a state, or your company should not inherit from Entity.

Comment: Thanks, I went with your "best solution" of removing the state from IEntity. Talking with the team it seems it was not giving as much benefit since probably all the concrete entities will have their own states with their own specific workflows and not all of them might have Inactive or Active.

Answer (score 0):

Just for exposing another way you could also use this model with an hidden backing field and not mapped states

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    State State { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    protected int InternalState { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public State State
    {
        get { return (State) InternalState; }
        set { InternalState = (int) value; }
    }

    // Entity is not a POCO class because of this :(
    // If we want to hide InternalState this is the only way to map it
    public class EntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
    {
        public EntityMap()
        {
            // Properties
            Property(t => t.InternalState)
                .HasColumnName("State");
        }
    }
}

public enum State
{
    Inactive = 0,
    Active = 1
}

public class Company : Entity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public new CompanyState State
    {
        get { return (CompanyState)InternalState; }
        set { InternalState = (int)value; }
    }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string SomeOtherProp { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Entity
{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string SomeOtherProp { get; set; }
}

public enum CompanyState
{
    Inactive = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Extra = 2
}
```

Comment: I'd like also to work on another solution without backing fields but actually is just an idea: you could use a class with singletons instead of enums and then map a property based on this class using entity framework ComplexType. But it's just an idea and I don't know if even c# model works.

Comment: Thanks, your solution does seem to work but I think just having an int for State looks cleaner. Anway, I removed the state from IEntity and only specific states because after talking with team we were not getting much benefit from having those base states.